# Jenkins Server Suddenly Fails. Cannot reach GUI

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, hudson, winstone

I setup a Jenkins server on a redhat linux VM a while back to run our unit and integration tests. It has worked without much trouble for about two months, but now I suddenly can no longer browse to the GUI/HUB. I don't believe I have changed anything (I know everyone says that :) ) however when I look at the logs I get the following errors

```
WARNING: Untrapped servlet exception
winstone.ClientSocketException: Failed to write to client
at winstone.ClientOutputStream.write(ClientOutputStream.java:41)
```

The Jenkins service is running, I have restarted it and the VM with no resolution to this issue. Even the jenkins jobs that I have written are still running as far as I can tell providing emails every now and again, but I cannot browse to the GUI. Anyone run into something like this before. I've searched for this issue and some people have been suggesting to re-install jenkins, but I am not trying to do that!

Comment: What version of Jenkins? There seems to be a known issue with 1.477:
https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-14825

Comment: hudson version 1.482 as specified by the config.xml file under /var/lib/jenkins/

Comment: While looking into the config file I also noticed that JAVA_OPTS was set to -Xms512 -Xmx2048. Since memory problems were one of the culprits I've been seeing online I figured I would post this info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

alright a long time later I finally figured it out. Turns out winstone was not the issue, but rather file permissions were to blame. Some of the files in my jenkins folder /var/lib/jenkins/ had root as their owner rather than jenkins. There were some in .m2 some in .grails and just scattered all about, not sure how this happened.

Anyway I just navigated to the home dir of jenkins /var/lib/jenkins and ran the following command

```
chown -R jenkins:jenkins jenkins
```